# How to rewrite this gulp.js task as webpack

Tags: gulp, webpack

I'm trying  to figure out if it is worthwhile moving to webpack, I am leaning towards saying no - figuring I have more important stuff to do - but I would like to see some practical examples of how to make webpack work.

So if I have the following Gulp.js task how would I do them as a webpack task?

```
    gulp.task('subpaths', ['clean_subpaths'],function() {
      //Minify and copy all JavaScript (except vendor scripts)
      gulp.src(paths.subpath_scripts)
        .pipe(fileinclude({
                prefix: '@@',
                basepath: '@file'
            }))
        .pipe(contextswitch())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(strip())
        .pipe(rename(function (path) {
                path.basename += timestamp;
         }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/longcache/javascripts/subpath'));
    });
```

So the tasks above do -

include files inside of other files for processing.

run the piped content through my own defined code - I guess in webpack 
that would be run my own plugin?

uglify

remove console statements

rename the output file so it has a version.

write out to a specific location

Answer (score 0):

The first item -- include files inside of other files -- is one of webpack's biggest benefits, speaking as someone coming from an all grunt/gulp workflow. Instead of managing dependencies externally (in your build tools), and having to ensure that files are combined correctly based on their runtime dependencies, with webpack your dependencies are part of the codebase, as `require()` expressions. You write your app as a collection of js modules and each module loads the modules it relies on; webpack understands those dependencies and bundles accordingly. If you're not already writing your js in a modular fashion, it's a big shift, but worth the effort. This is also a reflection of what webpack is meant for -- it's conceptually oriented around building a js application, not bundling some js that your site uses.

Your second item would more likely be a custom loader, which is easier to write than a custom plugin. Webpack is very extendable, throughout, but writing custom integrations is poorly documented.

Webpack's Uglify plugin will also remove console.logs, super easy.

Specifying output details is part of your basic webpack config, just a couple of options to fill in.